# How to sort an RDD of tuples with 5 elements in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

If I have an RDD of tuples with 5 elements, e.g., 
RDD(Double, String, Int, Double, Double)

How can I sort this RDD efficiently using the fifth element?

I tried to map this RDD into key-value pairs and used sortByKey, but looks like sortByKey is quite slow, it is slower than I collected this RDD and used sortWith on the collected array. Why is it like this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "it is slower than I collected this RDD and used sortWith on the collected array."  Of course it is. If you collect it, everything's on one node and you're then doing an in-memory sort Spark is for big datasets that don't fit on one node, and there's a (considerable) overhead compared to single-node computation. If you don't have that big a data set, you probably don't want to use Spark. It's not a magic "make things faster" solution.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with `sortBy` acting directly on the `RDD`:

```
myRdd.sortBy(_._5) // Sort by 5th field of each 5-tuple
```

There are extra optional parameters to define sort order ("ascending") and number of partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried sortBy on my RDD, but it returns an error:  value sortBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, String, Int, Double, Double)]. I am using Spark 1.0.1, is this the reason?

Comment: Looks like it might be - `sortBy` appears to date back to Spark versions 1.1.x

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort by descending order & if the corresponding element is of type int, you can use "-" sign to sort the RDD in descending order.

For ex:

I've a RDD of tuple with (String, Int). To sort this RDD by its 2nd element in descending order,

```
rdd.sortBy(x => -x._2).collect().foreach(println);
```

I've a RDD of tuple with (String, String). To sort this RDD by its 2nd element in descending order,

```
rdd.sortBy(x => x._2, false).collect().foreach(println);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sortByKey` is the only distributed sorting [API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/programming-guide.html) for Spark 1.0.

How much data are you trying to sort? Small amount will result in faster local/centralized sorting. If you try to sort GB and GB of data that may not even fit on a single node, that's where Spark shines.

Comment: Thanks. The data I sort is not very big and can be handled in memory. Maybe I should sort the data as a array/list rather than an RDD.